# need to add date picker in all the rows using Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

i have the view as the image attached. I want to add date picker for the column expiry date in all the rows.[image]

here the first row contains the id for the column expiry date is 'expiry_1_date'

```
2nd row -> 'expiry_2_date'
3nd row -> 'expiry_3_date'
4nd row -> 'expiry_4_date'
5nd row -> 'expiry_5_date'
```

Please help me to acheive the desired result in Jquery. thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @GautamD3164. i dont know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use starts with selector. and call the datepicker method.

try like this

```
$('input:text [id^="expiry_"]').datepicker();
```

or alternate way add a class to each text box.

then use like this

```
$('.SomeClass').datepicker();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwHNX/)

Comment: You should quote the query.

Comment: i want some design in that date picker. can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$("input[id^='expiry'][id$='date']").datepicker();
```

See [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vwHNX/1/)

and to add css to it try with this

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-datepicker {
       background: #333;
       border: 1px solid #555;
       color: #EEE;
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: i want some design in that date picker. can u help me?

Comment: i want some design in that date picker. can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) `[]` with `^`

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

try this

```
 $('input[id^="expiry_"]').datepicker();
```

Comment: You should quote the query.

Comment: i want some design in that date picker. can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

Set a input with a class `datepicker`

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

and then load it like :

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

You can get the date from it like:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker(
{
    onSelect: function()
    { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        alert(dateObject);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want some design in that date picker. can u help me?

Comment: paste the answer with some design

Answer (score 1):

You can select all element with id that [start with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) string `expiry` and assign `datepicker` to it:

```
$('input[id^="expiry"]').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pyMzT/